# C# Auto-Patch to Patch all Files in a Game Folder

Tags: c#, patch, auto-update

I have created a Game that consists of several folders like "Items" "Monsters" Etc. In the Launcher I have coded in C#, I want it to be able to **replace** all the update/overwrite/add selected files from my web server to those folders. How is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you do this with the [DirectoryInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the current version of the product, then check a database/web server to see if a new version is available.  If there is, pull the new version down, store it to the local file system.  Preferably it will be some type of archive.  Drop it in the root directory and extract it.  You can double check the Process list to see if the game is running, and either shut it down or throw an error when they try to update, so that you don't run into any file permission errors.   I know this is a very broad overview, but the question you have asked is a bit broad in scope of Stack Overflow.  We don't write your entire solution for you.